# Copy listview with fewer columns

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, listview

I have a listview on my asp page and I need to export it to excel in code behind(c#). However I don´t want all the columns to be exported.

Is it possible to copy the ListView into a new ListView object with fewer columns?
Or is there another way to export the listview with fewer columns into excel?

This is how I am exporting the code to excel in code behind:

```
protected void ExportToExcel(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
    string attachment = "attachment; filename=MyData.xls";
    Response.ClearContent();
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", attachment);
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel";
    Response.ContentEncoding = Encoding.Unicode;
    Response.BinaryWrite(Encoding.Unicode.GetPreamble());
    StringWriter stw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter htextw = new HtmlTextWriter(stw);                
    // How can I render myListView with fewer columns?
    myListView.RenderControl(htextw);
    Response.Write(stw.ToString());
    Response.End();
}
```

Thanks in advance,

Comment: how are exporting the content ?

Comment: hi, I added code to the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
class ListViewToCSV
{
    public static void ListViewToCSV(ListView listView, string filePath, bool includeHidden)
    {
        //make header srting
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        WriteCSVRow(result, listView.Columns.Count, i => includeHidden || listView.Columns[i].Width > 0, i => listView.Columns[i].Text);

        //export data rows
        foreach (var listItem in listView.Items)
            WriteCSVRow(result, listView.Columns.Count, i => includeHidden || listView.Columns[i].Width > 0, i => listItem.SubItems[i].Text);

        File.WriteAllText(filePath, result.ToString());
    }

    private void WriteCSVRow(StringBuilder result, int itemsCount, Func<int, bool> isColumnNeeded, Func<int, string> columnValue)
    {
        bool isFirstTime = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < itemsCount; i++)
        {
            if (!isColumnNeeded(i))
                continue;

            if (!isFirstTime)
                result.Append(",");
            isFirstTime = false;

            result.Append(String.Format("\"{0}\"", columnValue(i)));
        }
        result.AppendLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. The ListView object does not seem to recognize '.Columns' 
I get this error: `System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView does not contain a definition for Columns and no extension method Columns accepting a first argument of type System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListView could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Any idea why?